# JNA NativeKeyEvent to char

Tags: java, jna

Hi I'm using JNA and I'd like to convert a NativeKeyEvent to a char or String which I can then use in java, how would I conver the keycode back to a char?

When I use the .keyChar I get:

Key Typed -> Output

```
a -> 
s -> 
d -> 
f ->
```

Comment: Are you sure your question regards JNA and not JAutoClicker? The latter is the only project I find with "NativeKeyEvent".

Comment: Yes I'm using JNA here's the dependency:

 <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
            <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a method to manually convert them.